# is URDF usefull in real robot?

Tags: navigation, urdf, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am building a robot and want to ask if urdf file is important when comes to navigation and mapping in real world.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393070/is-urdf-usefull-in-real-robot-?/) by [offgrid8](https://answers.ros.org/users/89365/offgrid8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-12-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [muratkoc503](https://answers.ros.org/users/91043/muratkoc503/) on 2021-12-26**:
i think, this is usefull. Because, for example, footprint involved at common costmap parameter. This interested in robot's shape. This is relating for inflaction and costmap. But, if you use gazebo and rviz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In some cases, it would be required: Lidar slam packages like cartographer; Kalman filter packages like robot_localization.

If your robot will not use any existing packages that requires URDF file, you may skip it.

---

Originally posted by [Mingjie](https://answers.ros.org/users/122736/mingjie/) with karma: 26 on 2023-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1